# Only connect users to ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm using ActinCable on my application, and I have an issue with authorization. Currently actioncable tries to authorize every single person live on the site, repeatedly as-well.

This returns a constant stream of `An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected`in my log. Now that's because people visiting that aren't signed in, are also attempted to gain access.

My `connection.rb` looks like this:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

      def find_verified_user
        if current_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_id])
          current_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

now I'm wondering if I can make it so that only people that are signed in, try to become authorized by `connnection.rb`instead of every visitor using the site. I am too unfamiliar with ActionCable to know how to limit this - and the documentation for ActionCable are still in their early days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection attempt is when `ActionCable.createConsumer()` is called. You should try to call it only when user is logged in.